# How to redo a migration on django 1.8 after using --fake

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-1.8

Something went wrong on my migrations, I added a new datetimefield to a model then I used makemigrations and migrate.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

But after this the migrate got an "table already exists error". I supposed I could fake the migrations and start over, so I did

```
python manage.py makemigrations --fake core

Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: core
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying core.0001_initial... FAKED
  Applying core.0002_auto_20150525_1331... FAKED
  Applying core.0003_auto_20150525_1348... FAKED
  Applying core.0004_processo_data_atualizacao... FAKED
```

but the new migrate that I've just created was faked too (of course!).

How is the proper way to redo a migration (in this case the core.0004) after doing this?

Comment: In south it was possible to pass a specific step you wanted to migrate to. It would then migrate forward or backwards, to just after the given step. Was that feature dropped when they merged it into Django?

Comment: @spectras no it wasn't, it's exactly the same

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You should first set your current state to 0003 with `--fake` (assuming 0003 is the last migration you really have applied):

```
python manage.py migrate --fake core 0003
```

And then proceed as usual:

```
python manage.py migrate core
```

Relevant documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#migrate

Comment: what if it was the first migration that I used --fake on?

Comment: @EvyatarSivan you should use `zero` instead of migration number, e.g. `python manage.py migrate --fake core zero`

Comment: See also the `--fake-initial` flag https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#adding-migrations-to-apps.

Comment: FYI If you use `zero` instead of a migration number, you will lose any data in that table

Comment: Kindly note that `core` is the name of the app