# Django "You have 1 unapplied migration(s)" but last last migration is applied

Tags: django, django-migrations

So I had to reorganize my models ( had to do manual migrations) and in the end I had to rename some models and then I got an error, when I was running `manage.py migration:

```
The field Collect_data.Players.Team was declared with a lazy reference to 'xx.old_name', but app 'xxx' doesn't provide model 'old_name'.
```

the migration file:

```
    migrations.RenameModel(
        old_name='Old_name',
        new_name='new_name',
    ),
```

Now if look to the db, everything seems to be ok(renaming has been done) and all the connections are ok. If I open django shell, I can get the models with new names. Only problem is that I get this warning when I run server: "You have 1 unapplied migration(s)." and if I try to migrate, then I get a error that table already exists. If I run makemigartion I get same error as the first one said ( lazy reference... ). In migrations list I can see that the last migration doesn't have "X" on it's box. So how can I tell Django that everything is fine?

Comment: Did it apply **successfully**?

Comment: didn't get that message in the end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
python manage.py migrate --fake ####
```

This tells django to do a fake migration, basically check the migration checkbox without doing anything.
'####' is the migration file number you want to fake it

Comment: This did the job. Thanks. Here is more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626886/how-to-redo-a-migration-on-django-1-8-after-using-fake